# firebaseから取得したデータをReact内のjsxで表示できない

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

firebaseから取得したデータをreact componentで表示したいのですがundefinedが返され上手く表示されません。ライフサイクルの観点から上手くデータが同期されていない様に思うのですが、どなたかご教示いただく事は出来ないでしょうか。

```
class Grammer extends React.Component {
    
    state = 
        {
         N1:[],
         N2:[],
         N3:[]
        };

    componentDidMount(){
       const fetchData = () =>{
        firebase.database().ref("N3")
            .on(("value"),(snapshot)=>{
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
                    this.setState(()=>{
                        N3: this.state.N3.push({
                        id: childSnapshot.key,
                        ...childSnapshot.val()
                        })
                    });
                });
                console.log(this.state.N3[0])
            });
    };
    fetchData();
};

    render(){
        
        if(!this.state.N3[0]){
            return <div>Loading</div>
        }else if(this.state.N3[0]){
           return(
                <div>
                    <N3Grammer N3={this.state.N3}/>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

取得処理が非同期なので、データ取得してsetStateする前に、componentDidMountが終了して
Renderされているんじゃないでしょうか。
Promiseかasync,awaitで取得処理が終わるのを待てば反映されるかと思います。

【追記】
コメントではソース部分が書きにくい為、回答に編集で書きます。
仰る通りcomponentWillMountは非推奨になってますので
hooksを使用した版を下記に載せますので参考に

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();

export default () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const ref = db.collection("list");
      const snapShot = await ref.get();
      const list = snapShot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const item = doc.data();
        item.id = doc.id;
        return item;
      });
      setList(list);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。asyncとawaitを利用してsetStateを最初に実行させようとしたのですが、asyncとawaitをどの部分に加えたら良いか分からない状態です。いくつか試してみましたが上手くいかず、最終的な目標であるreutrn内コンポーネントへのstate表示のために、どちらにasyncとawaitを追加したら良いかご教示頂けないでしょうか

Comment: すみません、reactのライフサイクルで、componentDidMountの前に初回のrenderが呼ばれるからですね…
componentWillMountで行うとrenderの前に処理できそうです。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。componentWillMountは現在推奨されていないとのこ事で、UNSAFE_componentWillMountを利用してみたのですが、これでもrenderが先に実行されてしまう様です。また、constructor内で初期値を与える方法でも試してみたのですが同様にrenderが与えられる様です。両方を試したコードも上記で追記しましたので、間違っている部分をご指摘いただく事は出来ないでしょうか

Comment: 回答に追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。hookは経験がなかったので、頂いたものを参考に変更してみましたが上手くいかない様です。こちらはhookで実施しないと難しいものでしょうか。追記する形で編集後のコードを記載します

Comment: componentDidMountは初回のrender後に動くので、やるならconstructorですね。

Comment: 非同期処理の仕方という意味ではコンストラクタ―で行って解決して欲しいところですが、そもそもコンストラクタ―は初期化程度くらいにしておいた方が良く、
実際に今回のパターンの場合どうするのが良いかと言いますと、
render部でstate.N3が取得出来ているか(nullかどうか等)で取得出来ていない場合は、その部分を表示しないorローディング等を表示するようにして、
componentDidMountでstate.N3が取得出来次第render部で描画するというようにするのが一般的かなと思います。

Comment: ご指摘頂いた形にてsetStateが完了するまではif文でLoadingを表示する仕様としましたが、setStateが完了してもrenderが自動更新されない様です。こちらはpushでは浅く、concatにしないとダメという記事も読んだのですがいかがでしょうか。もしconcatを用いてどう修正したら良いかご教示頂けますととても助かります。宜しくお願いいたします

Comment: そこはreactの話になりますが、配列等のオブジェクトのstateを直接変更してもrenderには反映されない仕様ですので
this.setState(prevState => ({
    N3: [...prevState.N3, {取得してきた値}]
}))
所謂上記のようなスプレッド構文でオブジェクトを複製して追加のようにするといけると思います。

Comment: prevStateを用いて、firebaseより取得した値をcomponentに渡す事が出来ました。細かいところまでご丁寧にご教示頂き誠にありがとうございました。基礎的な部分より勉強し直して参ります